# Reactive Forms, push another form group to a specific index in the form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have inserted formgroup in my form array, now what I want to do is, on that formgroup, I want to push another form group on a specific index, I am working with this code but can't make it work.

```
//FORM
roomForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           roomNumber: ['', Validators.required],
           floorNumber: ['', Validators.required],
           type: ['', Validators.required],
           bedSpace: this.formBuilder.array([]),
           status: ['', Validators.required],
           tenant: [''],
           _id: ['']
  });
//GETTING THE bedSpace control
 get bedSpace() {
  return this.roomForm.get('bedSpace') as FormArray;
 }

//Adding form group to bedSpace control, p.s this is working fine
addBed() {
this.bedSpace.push(
    this.formBuilder.group({
      bedNumber: [bedNumber]

      })
  );
}

//Add new group to an existing form group in form array, this is the code 
that i cant make to work
addDeck(i: number) {
 this.roomForm.get(`bedSpace.${i}`).patchValue(
   this.formBuilder.group({
      deckNumber: [],
      status: [],
      dueRent: [],
      tenant: []
    })
);
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the json, What I want is to push the form group to index 0

[image]

```
       <div formArrayName="bedSpace">



        <div *ngFor="let bed of bedSpace.controls; let i = index">
          <mat-card fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" id="bed-panel">
            <span>
              BED
            </span>
            <span fxLayout="column" >
               <mat-icon id="remove-bed" 
    (click)="removeBed(i)">remove_circle_outline</mat-icon>
               <mat-icon id="add-deck" (click)="addDeck(i)">list</mat-icon>
            </span>
          </mat-card>
          <form [formGroup]="bed">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Bed number" 
    formControlName="bedNumber">
            </mat-form-field>
```

This is how i display the input field for decks FormGroup, i get this "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined" error, my guess is that it cannot see the "decks.controls" when it compiles, cause this is only added when I, add Deck, now my problem is where to put this "decks.controls".

```
            <div *ngFor="let deck of decks.controls; let i = index">
              <div [formGroup]="deck">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Deck number" 
   formControlName="deckNumber">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select placeholder="Bed status" 
   formControlName="deckStatus">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let bedStatus of 
   roomEnumService.roomBedStatus;" [value]="bedStatus">
                      {{bedStatus}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Due rent" 
   formControlName="dueRent">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Tenant" formControlName="tenant">
              </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying the API in https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray, I revised your code to below. Please check if that is what you want.

```
addDeck(i: number) {
  const bs = this.bedSpace.at(i) as FormGroup;
  let decks = bs.get('decks') as FormArray;
  if (!decks) {
    decks = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    bs.addControl('decks', decks);
  }
  decks.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    deckNumber: [],
    status: [],
    dueRent: [],
    tenant: []
  }));
}
```

Comment: hey, thank your for your reponse, tried above code, got this error    "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'."

Comment: Tried casting it, to form array like this       (this.bedSpace.at(i) as FormArray).push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
         deckNumber: [],
         status: [],
         dueRent: [],
         tenant: []
       })
    );  "got this error this.bedSpace.at(...).push is not a function"

Comment: Looks like bedSpace is a pure array? Can you try my modified one?

Comment: I have also tried your code, it has  this "Property 'push' does not exist on type AbstractControl" error.

Comment: Now I see the problem of your code. I revised mine. Please make a try.

Comment: Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'FormArray', got this error, with above code.

Comment: Where is this error coming from? I did not see code finding the control.

Comment: Check the modified code, I think that should be what you want.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, i can add deck, how ever only once, I want to add deck as many as possible.

Comment: Please check again if that is what you want.

Comment: thank you so much, I know I'm getting opportunist here, but can you help me out one more time, i need to display the input field for decks formGroup, i have added my code above, that i am working with.

Comment: Nevermind, after tinkering i have found a solution, i wish i could repay you someday your really save my ass man, you have no idea